# PHP optimization - json_decode

Tags: php

My PHP application is decoding about 100 json objects each request, I have many requests per secound, and I need to optimize my code. 
I was wondering if it would be faster to decode one huge json object instead of 100 smaller ones (assuming this big json was made by nesting the small ones). Anyone had similar issue ?

Comment: `$data = json_decode($data, true);`

Comment: Those ~100 json literals are sent with the request and there's no way around that?

Comment: with each request I need to fetch about 100 json encoded records from Redis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will nearly have the same performance with your two methods.

Check your requests time execution and response time with `Firebug` or similar.

After your test, it seems that your big json is slower than multiple mini json.

Comment: Quite interesting, I don't have you code source, maybe your merge is a huge operation.

Comment: I don't measure merge operation, I start counting time after merge is done